# Is there a way how to transfer a model inside simulation from ROS node?

Tags: ros-melodic, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm writing some automatic simulation testing and it would be helpful if I could just move the robot at it's initial position after each test instead of running the whole simulation again. How can I do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21671/is-there-a-way-how-to-transfer-a-model-inside-simulation-from-ros-node?/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2019-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can send a Gazebo message to the "/gazebo/default/model/modify" topic. See the message definition [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/582827025ea59c832cc50e33d64a07ae13cad76a/gazebo/msgs/model.proto?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

In the gazebo/gui/ModelListWidget.cc you have an example of how to publish some data towards that topic. See [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/582827025ea59c832cc50e33d64a07ae13cad76a/gazebo/gui/ModelListWidget.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

---

Originally posted by [Carlos Agüero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/280/carlos-ag%C3%BCero/) with karma: 626 on 2019-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0